# Can parentheses in C change the result type of operands of a bitwise operation?

Tags: c, type-conversion, bitwise-operators, parentheses

I have fed the following code through a static analysis tool:

```
u1 = (u1 ^ u2); // OK

u1 = (u1 ^ u2) & u3;  // NOT OK

u1 = (u1 ^ u2) & 10; // NOT OK

u1 = (u1 ^ u2) & 10U; // NOT OK

u1 = (unsigned char)(u1 ^ u2) & 10U; // OK

u1 = (unsigned char)(u1 ^ u2) & u3;  // OK
```

"OK" means the static analysis tool did not complain.
"NOT OK" means the static analysis tool did complain -- claiming that some operand of a bitwise operation is not an unsigned integer.

The results from the last 2 lines show that the parentheses are causing either

a. an actual type conversion to signed

b. something that the static analysis tool thinks is a type conversion to signed

I will ask the static analysis tool developer about (b).

But before I do, I would like to know if perhaps the C language is known to do (a)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing in C is done below `int`: eg when adding two `unsigned chars`, even before the addition, the operands are converted to `int` according to the default promotions.

```
unsigned char u1, u2, u3;
u1 = 0;
u2 = 42;
u3 = u1 + u2;
```

In the last line, first `u1` and `u2` are converted to `int`, then the `+` operator is applied to obtain a `int` value and then that value is converted back to `unsigned char` (of course the compiler can use shortcuts!)

Comment: Thanks @pmg! I'll leave the word "parentheses" in the question title because, even though now I know that they are irrelevant, others may also think they're what's causing the problem, search, and find this answer. Now I understand that this good answer is a special case of "learn C integer promotion rules". Lots of references out there (now that I know what to look for). E.g. http://tinyurl.com/62fm8yl on stackoverflow, and href="http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/c2.html#3-2" -- a discussion of "unsigned preserving and value preserving".

Answer (score 3):

This is because, in C, the resulting type of an operation on two `unsigned char`:s is `int`. The static analysis tool correctly (though not very intuitive) reports that the `&` is applied to an `int`.