# Can parentheses in C cause implicit cast?

Tags: c, type-conversion, bitwise-operators, parentheses

**Background**

The last time I asked about whether parentheses were causing implicit cast ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400258/can-parentheses-in-c-change-the-result-type-of-operands-of-a-bitwise-operation)), @pmg was nice enough to point out that "Nothing in C is done below int" But there, the discussion was about bitwise operators, and the parentheses turned out to be just a distraction.

**Introduction**

Below, the parentheses are the main attraction. Or, to be more boring but precise, the only operators I see are the parentheses and assignment operators.

[At this reference about the C parentheses operator](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/opers.html#parentheses), I do not see anything about parentheses changing the type (outside of typecast syntax, which is not this case).

Meanwhile, [here's a reference that reminds that there *is* automatic type conversion on assignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k630sk6z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but I don't think that will explain the static analysis tool behavior I will describe here.

As in my previous question, "OK" means that the static analysis tool did *not* warn about an *implicit type conversion*, and "NOT OK" means that it did.

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int  ui;
    int i;

    ui = (256U); // NOT OK (*) (1)
    i = (256U); // NOT OK (*)  (2)

    i = 256; // OK
    i = 256U; // NOT OK
    ui = 256U; // OK   (3)
    ui = 256; // NOT OK

 return(0);
}
```

I can understand them all except the first two - what do the parentheses do? If they do nothing in the way of implicit typecasting, then I would expect (1) to be OK and (2) to be NOT OK. If they do automatic type promotion of types smaller than int up to int, then I would expect (1) to be NOT OK and (2) to be OK. But this tool says that both are NOT OK.

Is this a static analysis tool error, or is the tool correct and there's something else I need to learn about implicit type conversions in C?

(BTW I hope that the value 256 is small enough not be causing overflow on my machine ...)

Comment: Your static analyzis tool is likely wrong. What tool are you using, and what are the errors it tells you ?

Comment: The C standard guarantees that the value of 256 will not overflow, not in arithmetic, not in the preprocessor -- unless it is assigned to a `char` of some kind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, let's clear up some terminology.  Nothing can cause an "implicit cast", because there is no such thing.  A *cast* is a explicit operator, consisting of a type name in parentheses preceding an expression, such as `(double)42`; it specifies a *conversion*.  Conversions can be either explicit (specified by a cast operator) or implicit, as in `double x = 42;`.  So what you're really asking is whether parentheses can cause an implicit *conversion*.

And the answer, at least in the code you've shown us, is no.

Quoting the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (3.7 MB PDF), section 6.5.1p5:

> A parenthesized expression is a primary expression. Its type and value
>   are identical to those of the unparenthesized expression. It is an
>   lvalue, a function designator, or a void expression if the
>   unparenthesized expression is, respectively, an lvalue, a function
>   designator, or a void expression.

And since `256U` is already a `primary expression`, the parentheses make no difference at all; parentheses generally indicate precedence, but in this case there is no predecence to indicate.

What static analysis tool are you using?  You should probably submit a bug report.

Comment: +1 from me too for same. I will be more careful with the terminology in future.

Answer (score 4):

The tool is confused somehow. There's no casting here. Those parentheses just indicate precedence.